# Use Google Ads API PHP Client without composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, google-ads-api, shared-hosting

Is it possible to use Google's API's without using a composer? When using shared hosting web servers one has not usually not access to use composer.

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/README.md

Comment: download the project zip from github and upload the files to your project

Comment: Develop the code locally, then push it to the live server. https://www.vagrantup.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Took me days to find a solution to this one.

Firstly, don't get the most recent Google API PHP Client.

The 2.x versions began using Composer, and frankly they also started becoming too big to be uploaded to a shared host. I'm sure hosts love that. For some, you then have to pay to get the PHP Client.

Upload the PHP Client, yes, but the two-year old version that came without Composer: [google-api-php-client v1.1.8](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/v1.1.8/src/Google). Download the zip file, but you need only upload the content you see here under a folder called: Google

Next, follow this article, [PHP server-side YouTube V3 OAuth API video upload guide](https://www.domsammut.com/code/php-server-side-youtube-v3-oauth-api-video-upload-guide/), as your guide. He's using a even older version, but ignore that. This article will get you through it. It's a Life-saver.

I don't know why I couldn't get the autoload.php to work with its `spl_autoload_register('google_api_php_client_autoload');`. For now, I just determined what I needed through trial and error and included the following 'require statements' at the start of my code:

```
<?php

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/src/Google/autoload.php';

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/src/Google/Config.php';

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/src/Google/Auth/Abstract.php';

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php';

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/src/Google/Http/Request.php';

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/src/Google/Utils.php';

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/src/Google/Client.php';

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/src/Google/Service/YouTube.php';

include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/src/CookieAPI.php');

session_start();
```

There!

You win!